# Why typeorm does not delete the table completely?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a **project** and **projectMember** entities. When i delete the project member i want it to remove the member completely. But seems my **projectMember** does not delete properly. Instead some columns value changed to **NULL**. But i want the table row to be deleted after i delete it. This is how implemented the deletion logic

**projecEntity**

```js
@Entity({ name: 'project' })
@Unique('project-organisationId_slug', ['organisation', 'slug'])
export class ProjectEntity
  extends AbstractEntity<ProjectId>
  implements ProjectEntityModel
{
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  address?: string;

  removeProjectMember(memberId: string) {
    if (!this.members) {
      this.members = [];
    }

    if (!this.hasOtherAdministrators(memberId)) {
      throw new MemberNotRemovableException(memberId);
    }

    const projectMemberIndex = this.getProjectMemberIndex(memberId);
    this.members.splice(projectMemberIndex, 1);
  }
}
```

**projectMemberEntity**

```js
import { ProjectEntity } from './project.entity';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'project_member' })
@Unique(['project', 'user'])
export class ProjectMemberEntity
  extends AbstractEntity
  implements ProjectMemberModel
{
  @ManyToOne(() => ProjectEntity, (project) => project.members, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @Index(['projectId'])
  project!: Relation<ProjectEntity>;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  @Index(['userId'])
  user!: Relation<UserEntity>;

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: ProjectRole,
    default: ProjectRole.Member,
  })
  role!: ProjectRole;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  projectJobTitle?: string;
}

export type ProjectMemberCreate = Omit<ProjectMemberEntity, 'id'>;
```

here my function to remove the member from the project

```js
  async removeProjectMember(
    projectIdentifier: ProjectIdentifier,
    memberId: string,
    organisationIdentifier: OrganisationIdentifier
  ): Promise<void> {
    const member = project.getProjectMember(memberId);
    project.removeProjectMember(memberId);
    await this.projectRepository.save(project);
    await this.projectMemberRepository.delete(memberId);
    await this.activityLogWriterService.createFromProject({
      project,
      currentUserSub: user?.legacyAuth0Id ?? '',
      activityUser: member.user,
      activity: ProjectActivityLogWriterType.PROJECT_MEMBER_REMOVED,
    });
    this.eventEmitter?.emit('project.updated', project.id);
  }
```

When i delete the member see in my pgAdmin console only change some columns to null, but it does not remove or delete it completely
[image]